# How do I write values to a google spreadsheets row with the api?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want, in node.js, for my command to, on the second row of my spreadsheet, set the values of A-D to 1-4. The code below seems to be how the documentation wants me to do it, but I keep getting the following error:

"GaxiosError: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "majorDimension": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'majorDimension' could not be found in request message.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "values": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'values' could not be found in request message."

```
const {google} = require("googleapis")
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
      keyFile: "sheets-credentials.json",
      scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
});
const client = await auth.getClient();
const googleSheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth: client });
const spreadsheetId = "anidthisis";
await googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
      auth,
      spreadsheetId,        
      "range": "Sheet1!A2:D2",
      "majorDimension": "ROWS",
      "values": [
          ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
       ],
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
await googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
      auth,
      spreadsheetId,        
      "range": "Sheet1!A2:D2",
      "majorDimension": "ROWS",
      "values": [
          ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
       ],
});
```

##### To:

```
await googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
  auth,
  spreadsheetId,
  range: "Sheet1!A2:D2", // or "Sheet1!A2"
  valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
  requestBody: { majorDimension: "ROWS", values: [["1", "2", "3", "4"]] },
});
```

- In this case, when the cells "A2:D2" are not empty, the values are appended. So if you want to put the values to the cells "A2:D2" even when the cells "A2:D2" are not empty, how about the following modification?

  ```
    await googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
      auth,
      spreadsheetId,
      range: "Sheet1!A2:D2", // or "Sheet1!A2"
      valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
      requestBody: { values: [["1", "2", "3", "4"]] },
    });
  ```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

Comment: This works, thank you so much!

Comment: @TGercken Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.